# Justify image in flex container so it doesn't stretch. Then add JS carousel (multiple images)

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, slick.js

This problem is best broken into two parts:

- **Layout:** Horizontally centre an image with the container wrapping around the height/width of the content (no space).
- **Carousel:** Add a carousel to display a slideshow of images in this space.

The reason I've broken this into two parts is I tried to use [slick.js](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for a carousel and it broke the layout (example below). So thought I best get a solid UI before re-introducing that.

**1. Layout**

This was working in Chrome but checking Firefox and Safari (Mac OS), I realised my approach was flawed. Played around with various declarations for `flex` but no luck. I thought I'd resolved the issue with `overflow: hidden;` on the parent of the `img` but that only fixed the layout in Chrome. Removing this at least seems to show a consistent results across the x3 browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) I'm looking at.

Layout works fine if you view in Chrome: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/NWaObyW

**2. Carousel**

For reference, as my end goal is to use a carousel (so multiple images) in this space. I thought it was worth showing what happened in all 3 browsers when I added in slick.js.

Link: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/xxXyRmW

So the layout totally breaks. Obviously me not the plug-in!

I don't need to use slick.js. I used it I found a way to include a dynamic count (1 of 3) when changing slides.

I'm looking to fade or slide between images. Display the counter and a caption *(which I was thinking of using a `data` attribute)* to add the text to a div outside. So I'm open to something else if it's not possible to use slick.js with this layout.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues :

- `slickjs` doesn't like its container to be a `flex` element
- There are several way to fix `slickjs` not working on firefox, one way I find not too messy is to refresh it right after its init

I fixed some of your CSS (grid container, flex containers...), I also added some extra wrappers in your HTML. Flex elements must be separated from your gallery stuff.

```js
var $status = $('.slick-count');
var $slickElement = $('.slick');

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
  var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
  $status.text(i + ' / ' + slick.slideCount);
});

$slickElement.slick({
  autoplay: true,
  dots: false,
  arrows: false
});

$slickElement.slick("refresh");
```

```css
html {
    background: white;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: white;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

/**
 * Base `body` styling.
 */

body {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures discretionary-ligatures historical-ligatures;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.grid__item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 24px 24px 0;
}

.gallery {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

    .grid {
    background-color: black;
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 2px;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    }

    .grid__item {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .gallery {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
  
  .gallery img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
  }
    
    /* img {
        object-fit: contain;
        max-height: none;
    } */
  .grid__item-header {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
  
    .grid__item-footer {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin-top: auto;
    }
    
    .grid__item-footer .gallery-count {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 0%;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        
    }
}

.slick-track,
.slick-slider,
.slick-list {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">

  <div class="grid__item">
    
    <div>
    <h1 class="brand-name">Brand Name</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
    <p class="grid__item-footer">Footer Item</span></p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid__item">
  <div class="grid__item-header">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="slick">
        <div><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/850" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/850" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p class="grid__item-footer">Name of Project <span class="slick-count"></span></p>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I forgot how sometimes you need to wrap multiple divs with flex for alignment. So that make sense.

If there's issues with slick.js would you advise a lighter JS solution? I just need images to fade (or slide) and update a caption and the "1 / 5" at the bottom accordingly.

Looks like there's a JS error in the example but might just be jQuery isn't called?

Comment: Ah just realised the `max-width` won't do it. If I used that I could just add `margin: 0 auto` and remove flex. But I want it to fill the available space/height of the parent and centre itself.

Comment: slickjs isn't the best library but it's pretty light!

Comment: I'm not sure what result you're expecting

Comment: Yeah I've always used slickjs because of how versatile it is. Maybe I try something else this time though just because of the UI with flex. Maybe just a lightweight / fade plugin.

Comment: For the UI result, this works in Chrome: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/NWaObyW - so basically there's no set width. The image/div is just centred in the space but always takes up the full height. So it adjusted/changes on resize - which you can see if you drag the window around. Does that make sense?